# Why did Nick Fury want Spider Man to become suspicious?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *[Spider-Man: Far From Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home)*, Nick Fury wants Spider-Man to fight to which Spider-Man disagrees:

> Spider Man: If I'm seen in Europe after the Washington Monument, my
>   class will figure out who I am, then...Then the whole world  will
>   figure out who I am, and then I'm done.
>
> Nick Fury: I understand.
>
> Spider Man: I'm sorry, what?
>
> Nick Fury: Why don't you get back before your teachers miss you and
>   **become suspicious**.

Why did Nick Fury want Spider-Man to become suspicious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### He didn't

Fury here is saying that Peter's teachers/classmates might become suspicious with Peter going missing again. The *"become suspicious"* is part of the first part of the sentence to attached to the *"teachers miss you"* part.

Comment: Do you mean "The 'become suspicious' is not part of the first part of the sentence, but is attached to the 'teachers miss you' part"